# Usage of multiple output function with ddply

Tags: r, function, plyr

I have a function that returns more than one value. I need to use it in `ddply` but I want to avoid calling the function multiple times. Here's a mock-up example:

```
library(plyr)

ff = function(i) {
  return(c(min(i),max(i)))
}

set.seed(12345)
id = c(rep(1:3,4))
x  = sample(1:10, 12, replace=T)
df = data.frame(id,x)

res = ddply(df,.(id),summarise,val1 = min(x), val2 = max(x), val3 = ff(x)[1], val4 = ff(x)[2])
View(res)


    id  val1    val2    val3    val4
1   1   4   10  4   10
2   2   1   9   1   9
3   3   2   8   2   8
```

As expected, `val3 = val1`, and `val4 = val2`. But I have to call function `ff` two times in `ddply`, which is not optimal time-wise. Is there a way to assign `val` within `ddply` with both function outputs in one access? If I try to use `[1:2]` or similar, I get an error: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE`

Thanks!

Edit. Thanks to all contributors! David's solution worked ~2 times faster. And it allows one to do further operations with intermediate results. Here's an updated code that is fully reproducible.

```
library(plyr)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

ff = function(i) {
  return(c(min(i),max(i)))
}

set.seed(12345)
id = c(rep(1:3,4000))
x  = runif(12000,1,10)
df = data.frame(id,id2,x)
View(df)

res  = ddply(df,.(id),summarise,val1 = min(x), val2 = max(x), val3 = ff(x)[1], val4 = ff(x)[2], val5 = val3+val4, val6 = val3/val4)
View(res)

res2 = setDT(df)[, as.list(c(val1 = min(x), val2 = max(x), val3 = ff(x))), .(id)][, val5 := val31+val32][, val6 := val31/val32]
View(res2)

print(microbenchmark(ddply(df,.(id),summarise,val1 = min(x), val2 = max(x), val3 = ff(x)[1], val4 = ff(x)[2], val5 = val3+val4, val6 = val3/val4), times = 100))
print(microbenchmark(setDT(df)[, as.list(c(val1 = min(x), val2 = max(x), val3 = ff(x))), .(id)][, val5 := val31+val32][, val6 := val31/val32],times=100))
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                                                   expr
 ddply(df, .(id), summarise, val1 = min(x), val2 = max(x), val3 = ff(x)[1],      val4 = ff(x)[2], val5 = val3 + val4, val6 = val3/val4)
      min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
 3.042616 3.185358 5.976851 3.409828 3.925104 45.5157   100
Unit: milliseconds
                                                                                                                                    expr
 setDT(df)[, as.list(c(val1 = min(x), val2 = max(x), val3 = ff(x))),      .(id)][, `:=`(val5, val31 + val32)][, `:=`(val6, val31/val32)]
      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 1.968349 2.071747 2.285368 2.124206 2.251171 12.62967   100
```

Comment: You can simply do `aggregate(x ~ id, df, ff)`....

Comment: @DavidArenburg, you are right, thank you! That will work in a simple case. But in addition to `ff`, I do some extra calculations in `ddply` "body", e.g. `sum` of x values for each `id`.

Comment: For a simple case, how do I easily get the desired output as shown above with 3 rows, and not the 6-row one from `aggregate` ? Thanks!

Comment: `aggregate(x ~ id, df, function(x) c(min(x), max(x), ff(x)))` Though this will only print nicely. In order to get the actual result, something like `do.call(as.data.frame, aggregate(x ~ id, df, function(x) c(min(x), max(x), ff(x))))` should do.

Comment: Another nice option is `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[, as.list(c(min(x), max(x), ff(x))), id]`

Comment: Thanks, @DavidArenburg. I tried all three options, and surprisingly it looks like my original method with two-time access is faster, per `microbenchmark`. `print(microbenchmark(ddply(df,.(id),summarise,val1 = min(x), val2 = max(x), val3 = ff(x)[1], val4 = ff(x)[2]), times = 100))
print(microbenchmark(aggregate(x ~ id, df, function(x) c(min(x), max(x), ff(x))),times=100))` . Results (I increased vector size by 100 in original message): 2.2 ms, 4.4 ms, 4.3 ms
print(microbenchmark(do.call(as.data.frame, aggregate(x ~ id, df, function(x) c(min(x), max(x), ff(x)))),times=100))

Comment: Did you benchmark the `data.table` approach?

Comment: Ah! `data.table` gives 0.95 ms. Very nice! Thank you. I'll see if I can convert all my `ddply` calculations without breaking the code. Hopefully, grouping by more than one variable is as easy as `.(id,SomeOtherVar)`

Comment: You can also do this with `dplyr` (though I find it quite awkward), but it won't allow you run the exact same function twice on the same variable and you will have to modify `ff` too. Here is an example while adding `mean(x)`. `ff  <- list(~ min(x), ~max(x));
library(dplyr);
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise_(~mean(x), .dots = ff)`

Comment: What if I need to calculate smth using results from `ff`, e.g. min/max. Assigning `var` in ddply is easy and then use them. How do I go around it in `data.table` and one single access to `ff` ? [P.S. Are we breaking community rules with extended comments?]

Comment: Could probably do something like `setDT(df)[, as.list(c(var1 = min(x), var2 = max(x), var3 = ff(x))), id]`

Comment: Almost could. Probably not using proper calls to it. E.g. `var3 = ff(x)`, and then need `var3[1] / var3[2]` in the same body of as.list. Got error var31 etc not found

Comment: You could potentially mimic `plyr` behavior, but you will need to specify it by hand again as in `df[, {var1 <- ff(x)[1] ;
             var2 <- ff(x)[2] ;
             var2/var1}, by = id]`

Comment: Or even something worse as `df[, as.list({var1 = ff(x)[1] ; var2 = ff(x)[2] ; c(var1 = var1, var2 = var2, var3 = var2/var1)}), by = id]`. But I'm wondering, couldn't you just modify `ff` to `ff = function(i) {
  min(i)/max(i)
}` and get over with?

Comment: My functions are more complicated than min, max. So I was looking just for a general solution. Your `{var1 <- ff(x)[1] ; var2 <- ff(x)[2] ; var2/var1}, by = id]` will result in two calls, as in my original code.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that. You also could chain it, something like `df[, as.list(c(var1 = min(x), var2 = max(x), var3 = ff(x))), id][, var4 := var31/var32][]`. But I'm not entirely sure what are you needs/restrictions

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you very much! Your solution worked for me. The syntax might seem a bit more cumbersome, but it gives a nice speed up. Would you like to furnish an answer that I can accept as the best one?

Comment: I'm not feeling very comfortable with this solution as I feel I'm not fully understand your problem and I have a feeling it can be solved in a less cumbersome way. It doesn't make sense to me that `data.table` is just slightly more efficient than `plyr`, it should be about X100 faster at least. I guess you can post your code as a solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you construct your function to return a named vector, then data.table will accept it and populate the columns with those names retruning the desired structure:

```
require(data.table)
 ff = function(i) {
   return(c(val3=min(i),val4=max(i)))
   }
setDT(df)[, as.list(c(var1 = min(x), var2 = max(x),  ff(x))), id]
#-----------
   id var1 var2 val3 val4
1:  1    4   10    4   10
2:  2    1    9    1    9
3:  3    2    8    2    8
```

Comment: I've already [proposed that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218284/usage-of-multiple-output-function-with-ddply?noredirect=1#comment46646349_29218284), and we are already past that step in the comments chain as the OP wants [further manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218284/usage-of-multiple-output-function-with-ddply?noredirect=1#comment46648591_29218284) of the data in that step.